# Finding the range of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

The book says Define $T:\mathbb{P}_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T(\vec{p})=\begin{bmatrix} \vec{p}(0)\\\vec{p}(1)\\\end{bmatrix}$ Describe the range of $T$?. This im stuck on. So what I have so far is let $\vec{p}\in\mathbb{P}_2$ where $\vec{p}=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2$. Then $$T(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2)=\begin{bmatrix} a_0\\a_0+a_1+a_2\\\end{bmatrix}$$ which can be rewritten as
$$T(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\\end{bmatrix}$$  Then row reducing the column matrix we get $$T(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\\end{bmatrix}$$ From here I know im supposed to find the column space of the coefficient matrix I think which spans the range which I don't get how to find from here.

Comment: The range of a matrix coincides with its column space. You only need to find a basis for the column space of A

Comment: would it be the three columns then of the coeffient matrix?

Comment: Yes, find a basis for the column space of the reduced matrix.

Comment: Well my basis for the column space would be $${\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\\end{bmatrix}}\}$$

Comment: Basically,  look at the three column vectors you have; $(1,0)^T$, $(0,1)^T$, and $(0,1)^T$, reduce, and find a basis for the reduced form; you have two equal vectors, so the 1st, 2nd vectors, say, are a basis for the column space.

Comment: So it spans all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since Col A=span ${\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\\end{bmatrix}}\}$

Comment: Since the column space is a subspace it spans all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Would that be a correct explanation?

Comment: Yes, you're right; the range is a subspace, and it is a 2-d subspace of $\mathbb R^2 $, so it must be the whole of $\mathbb R^2$ , since the only n-dimensional subspace of an n-dimensional space V is V itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem, good job.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this by matrix techniques. But, sometimes, it's much faster to address the problem directly in the notation which you're given. (unless of course this exercise is intended to make you sort through the matrix representation ideas... so continue what you're doing, I merely add this to show you another path here)

Or, you could look for polynomials $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ such that $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$ and $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. If you could find such polynomials then 
$$ T(af(t)+bg(t)) = (af(0)+bg(0), af(1)+bg(1))=(a,b)$$ 
hence $T$ is onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, can you find these polynomials without much effort?

Hint: two points determine a line.